# How to store 00 instead of 0 as DEFAULT to integer field in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to store 00 instead of 0 as DEFAULT to integer field in mysql ?

i did 00 as default but it is storing just 0.

Comment: If the numbers are all less than 100, then you can set the column to be `TINYINT(2) UNISNGED ZEROFILL` - however this will result in values like `01`, `02`, ... so make sure this is what you want before doing it ;)

Comment: Integer values do not have leading zeros, not ever – otherwise they wouldn’t _be_ integers. (And zerofill does not actually store leading zeroes, it just makes the _selected_ values have zeroes.)

Comment: No, numbers are going to be big, but it would work if it starts with 00, 01 , 02....

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the motivation for this?

Comment: Okay it means i have to make a php rule then

Comment: @ypercube , you can assume it to be simple numbers. A little bit fancy way to show

Comment: This is sad, i was just asking, why people negative votes :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer can never be stored as "00" because it will always be evaluated to 0 (zero).

Use a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` type for your field instead to guarantee this representation of the value.

If you want your website / application to show a leading zero in front of your numbers, you can take care of that in PHP with help of `str_pad()`.

Comment: +1 It's generally a good idea to keep your data and your presentation of the data separate, as silkfire suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store `00` in a column of type integer, because `00` isn't an integer.

You can format the integer `0` to *appear* as if it's `00`, but that won't change its value.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the numbers stored as integers.

Then use function [**`LPAD()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to show the numbers (left) padded with zeros:

```
SELECT LPAD( 0, 2, '0') AS padded;

| padded |
-----------
|     00 |
```

If the number of zerofill characters is variable, add another column in the table with that (zerofill) length.